# How to keep the same schema's column order with Spark Dataset's map?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I'm reading data from a Hive table and then trying to enrich it with an extra column that is derived from the other columns.
But I'm having issues with Spark changing my schema and ordering all columns by name.

After calling withColumn() and encoding it with my enriched class the schema is correct but whenever I call map() the schema changes and the order of the columns is wrong. How can I tell Spark to keep the original order of the columns?

```
session.table("myTable")
    .as(Encoders.bean(Base.class))
    .withColumn("enrichedColumn", lit(""))
    .as(Encoders.bean(Enriched.class))
    .map(enriched -> enriched.enrich(), Encoders.bean(Enriched.class))
    .printSchema();
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I assume you have the same fields in Base and Enriched, with Enriched having just one more column. Do you have the same order in both classes?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the small piece of code, but I forsee a problem with your model here.

You have to make sure Enriched.class and Base.class have the same ordered fields.

So for example, this won't provide the same order:

```
Base:
 x;
 y;

Enriched:
 y;
 x;
```

won't be ordered the same...